# iterating through array of objects with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, each

I am trying to iterate through data on success in an AJAX call.  The data, when logged in console looks like this:

```
[Object, Object]
0: Object
  messages: Array[0]
  sid: 534
__proto__: Object
1: Object
   messages: Array[0]
   sid: 535
```

The javascript I am using is this:

```
 function startMsgCheck() {
    msgCheck = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/sepanel/chat/check_for_msg',
      type:'POST',
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each([data], function(i, val){
          var SID = data[i].sid
          if ( data[i].messages.message_id == $('#chat_message_ID_' + SID).val()) {
            return false;
          }
          else {
            var buildMsg = '<p><b>' + data[i].messages.name + '</b>(' + data[i].messages.time_stamp + ')<b>:</b> ' + data[i].messages.message + '</p>'

            $('#chat_messageID_' + SID).val(data[i].messages.message_id).text();

              $(buildMsg).appendTo("#tab-" + SID);

            $("#tab-" + SID).prop({ scrollTop: $("#tab-" + SID).prop("scrollHeight") });
            if (data.name == data[i].messages.agent_name){
              return false;
            }
            else {
            $('#li_' + SID).removeClass('active');
            $('#li_' + SID).removeClass('inactive');
            $('#li_' + SID).addClass('notify');
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
    }, 1000);
   }
```

The problem I am having is that this is only working properly for the first object in the array.  I can access the values for the [0] object but its not going through [1] ( or [2],[3] etc - when those objects exist).

I may be confused about this being an array at all, is the data coming back actually an object of objects? should I be using $.each at all ot should this be a for loop? if it should be a for loop how would I implement that? I am not sure what I am doing wrong, so if anyone can steer me in the right direction I would appreciate that.

Comment: Your code block is a little messed up, it doesn't include the last line.

Comment: You're iterating over this array: `[data.index]` - from your console output however there is no "index" property in the returned JSON object (which appears to be an array with two objects in it).

Comment: I would say the same as Pointy. Or you use `each(data, ` or read like this `data.index[i]`. One of those two should work.

Comment: i removed the .index and edited the question. however the behaviour is the same.  it goes through the first object but not the second.  I have also tried data without the [] brackets and that also produces the same behaviour.

Comment: You're **still** putting your array inside **another** array. It should be `$.each(data, function() ...`

Comment: @Tallmaris - ran the code without the return false and still the same behaviour

Comment: Yeah sorry that was a silly comment :( . Anyway, since you are iterating through with `$.each` can you try use `val` in your function instead of using `data[i]`? Also, you can use Chrome debugger and step through to see where it exits...

Comment: Also, inside the `.each` callback, you should be referring to `val`, not `data[i]`.

Comment: @pointy removed the [] brackets and it works now.  Thanks

Comment: If data.name and data[i].messages.agent_name are both undefined (which I think they are based on your log output), then you will terminate the loop because undefined == undefined -> true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was the [] brackets around data in the each loop.  Solution by pointy in the comments to the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the console output, it looks like the `data` variable has this structure:

```
var data = [
    {
        messages: [...],
        sid: 1
    },{
        messages: [...],
        sid: 2
    }
];
```

Given this structure, you can iterate over it like this:

```
$.each(data, function(i, val) {
    var sid = val.sid;

    $.each(val.messages, function(j, message) {
        // do something with message
    });
});
```